# Outer measure : $\mu^*(A)\leq \mu(A)$?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a premeasure on a semi ring $\mathcal{P}$. For every $E\in P(X)$ let $\mathcal{C} (E)$ denote the set of all countable-$\mathcal{P}$ covers of $E$.

Defining $\mu^{*} (E)=\inf\{\sum_n \mu(A_n): \{A_n : n\in \mathbb{N}\}\in \cal{C}
 $$(E)\}$

If $A\in\mathcal{P}$ then clearly the family $\{A\}$ is a countable-$\mathcal{P}$ cover of $A$

In the second line of a proof it states that $\mu^*(A)\leq\mu(A)$.
But I don't understand exactly why...

Sorry for such a trivial question, if this is a duplicate please notify!

Comment: First all all, $A$ is not guaranteed to be measurable yet, and you cannot take $\mu (A)$, for an arbitrary set $A$. Secondly, could you show how do you get $\mu^*(A)\leq\mu(A)$? The direction should be reversed.

Comment: I'm simplifying a lot to not mix up the matter.
$\mu$ is a premeasure on a semi-ring

Comment: But then what is $A$? I know $A_n$

Comment: Please add details to this question. You should say that $\mu$ is a pre-measure, and what sort of space you are defining it for, which sets you are questioning the inequality for. You could also include why you believe the inequality to be true in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I have edited the question adding all the necessary details

Comment: @YujieZha $A \in \mathcal{P}$. I have reworded the question hopefully in a more clear manner

Comment: @Malcolm cool, it is much clearer, and I've provided an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=(e,f]$, let $A_1= A$, and $A_2=A_3=...=\emptyset$.

Then $A \subset \cup_{i =1}^{\infty}A_i$, hence

$$\mu^{*}(A) \le \Sigma_{i = 1}^{\infty} \mu(A_i) = \mu(A_1) = \mu(A)$$

**EDIT**

Notice the above inequality is by the definition of outer measure.

$$\mu^{*}(E) = \inf B$$, where $B = \{\sum_n \mu(A_n): \{A_n : n\in \mathbb{N}\}\in \cal{C}
 $$(E)\}$ is essentially a set of real numbers.

Thus $\forall b \in B$, we have $\mu^{*}(E) \le b$, and $\Sigma_{i=1}^{\infty} \mu(A_i)$ is one valid element in $B$

Comment: How did you determine that $\mu^*(A)\leq \sum_n\mu(A_n)$?

Comment: @Malcolm By definition of it. It is the inf of sum of measure of all the countable covers of a set. Which means given any cover, by definition, outer measure is smaller than the sum of their measures. I've edited for more explanations

Comment: @Malcolm Let me know of you have any questions, I understand when you first touch those materials, it's gonna be difficult, but after a while, you'll get used to it :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I've been studying for a bit and the basics are seeming more difficult than they should.
Your answer was very informative! Thank you for taking the time to answer so fully!

Comment: @Malcolm You are welcome, and best luck!